# Gestures on Fragment not working

Tags: android, gesture

I had searched and implemented every given answers from the other question with the same issue but still to no avail in my case. What I want to achieve is to change the content of the textviews inside my fragment when I swipe to either left or right.
Here's my code that I implemented from other questions here in SO.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_fragment, container, false);

    gDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("Down", "Down triggered!");
            return super.onDown(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            Log.d("Fling", "Motion detected!");

            // swipe left
            if(start.getX() - finish.getX() > 50){

                if(pos != 0){
                    pos --;
                    showLesson();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You've reached the first lesson.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else if(finish.getX() - start.getX() > 50){

                if(pos != LessonListFragment.lessonsList.size()){
                    pos ++;
                    showLesson();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You've finished all the lessons.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            return super.onFling(start, finish, velocityX, velocityY);
        }
    });

    contentView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return gDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    });

    pos = getArguments().getInt("index");

    topic = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_frag_topic);
    topic_des = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_frag_desc);
    syntax = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_frag_syntax);
    example = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_frag_example);

    try_example = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_try);
    try_example.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Show practice activity.
        }
    });

    lesson_content_container = (FrameLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_content_container);

    tip_msg = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.tip_msg);
    tip_msg.setText(R.string.lesson_content_tip);

    close_tip = (ImageButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.close_tip);
    close_tip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            lesson_content_container.removeViewAt(1);
        }
    });

    showLesson();

    return contentView;
}
```

and here's the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lesson_content_container">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/min_padding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lesson_frag_topic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lesson_frag_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/span_top" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:text="@string/syntax"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lesson_frag_syntax"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/example"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lesson_frag_example"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lesson_frag_syntax"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/textViewStyle"
            android:id="@+id/lesson_try"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/min_btn_height"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Try It!"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include
    layout="@layout/tip_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Post the whole `onCreateView()`, currently it has not closing bracket. What do you return?

Comment: `What I want to achieve is to switch the content of the fragment when I swipe to either left or right.` Which step exactly you are failing at?

Comment: The swipe gestures isn't firing at all, as you can see in my codes, I added some `Log.d()` in onDown and onFling method, but my logcat is not showing those so I assume that the gesture isn't triggered at all.

Comment: `The swipe gestures isn't firing at all` Are you performing gestures on some views, that are in that layout? E.g. you click on `Button` and you expect `onDown()` to get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

The gesture event that I implement wasn't working because I had a scrollview as a first child of the framelayout. My theory is that the scrollview itself implements its own gestrure (which I think intercepts the implemented gesture) event or maybe I should've set onTouchEvent not on my framelayout but on my scrollview. Hope someone could clarify this for future reference :D